# Javascript create dynamic global array

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to create a dynamic global array of integers in javascript. This is the code I've got:

```
function LoadStarmap()
{
    Request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    Request.onreadystatechange 
    = 
    function()
    {
        if( Request.readyState == 4 && Request.status == 200 )
        {
            var Data = Request.responseText;
            alert( Data );
            eval( Data );
        }
    }

    Request.open( "POST", "GetMap", true );
    Request.send();
}
```

(This alert does show)
Data looks like this:

```
var window.StarCords = [ [12,32], [21,32], ... ];
```

In another function I have:

```
if ( typeof StarCords != 'undefined' ) 
{
   alert( 'got here' );
}
```

Why doesn't this alert show? (The function does execute).
I tried moving all sorts of stuff about, but nothing I do works, and I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

**Edit:**

Yes, oops I can see what you guys are thinking. I failed to mention that that second alert is running inside a loop. So it also executes after the LoadStarmap() has been called. Sorry for not mentioning that before.

It resiedes in the Rendermain function:

```
var intervalIDRender = setInterval( RenderMain, 10);
```

Sorry about this, it's late.

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous....you need to consume the response within `onreadystatechange` callback

Comment: `var window.StarCords = [ [12,32], [21,32], ... ];` is invalid JavaScript.

Comment: The problem lies not with the ajax, it's all working. @Qantas 94 Heavy, you mean that that's not how to declare a multidimensional array?

Comment: @user513647: variable declarations are done as `var x = 1;`, while property assignments are done using `window.y = 2;`. If you're doing a property assignment, you shouldn't be using `var`. Try what you wrote in the console and see what happens.

Comment: Yep, that was it. This is the first time I do developing in javascript, I missed that, changing the code to 'window.starcords = [...' did it.